# axios delete call returns 405

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, tornado

We are running a Tornado service in the background which accepts post and delete calls from the React application.

Our **axios.post call works perfectly fine** but it fails on our delete request with the following error message

*405 (Method Not Allowed)*

*Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.*

```
export const StopBuild = (action$) =>
  action$.ofType(STOPBUILD)
    .mergeMap((action) => {
      return Observable.fromPromise(axios.delete(action.stopRequest))
        .map(response => PlatformBuildSuccess(response))
        .catch(error => Observable.of(PlatformBuildFailure(error, action.platform)))
    })
```

From server side, this is what we have currently set,

```
    self.set_header("Content-Type", "*")
    self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")
    self.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE')
```

Something else we noticed that when on the server side we only set the following header POST call still works. I think we are going wrong on the server end.

```
self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This likely means that POST is listed in Access-Control-Allow-Methods and DELETE isn't.

Comment: Could you provide the server's response to an OPTIONS request?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, allow cors in your API request:
Like this :

```
axios.delete(url, { crossdomain: true }) // an example
```

you can take this as an example and add `crossdomain:true` in your delete request.
let me know if cors error still persists.

Answer (score 0):

This is a CORS issue. As the error states it, the `DELETE` operation is not allowed yet. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Methods) is explained that you have to add the `DELETE` method to the `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` response header of the preflight request.

On server side, using nodejs, allowing CORS would look like this:

```
const corsMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*')
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS, POST, DELETE')
  next()
}

app.use(corsMiddleware)
```

The request can be made from all origins with all headers, and `OPTIONS`, `POST` and `DELETE` methods are allowed.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Please see the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

For `CORS` request there is one package available called `cors`. You can try that by installing it as,

```
npm install cors --save
```

then you can require it and use that as middleware here the example,

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

app.use(cors());
```

More on cors npm package [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)